# Stylusに記述するまでの流れ

Tags: css

画像を参照してください。

ここで質問ですが

1. 左の枠で囲ったコードに対応するのは右の青枠で囲んであるDOMの事か
   これが記述されていれば、下にStylesがあり、その中から変更すべきCSSを変える
2. Stylusに記述するコードは下記の事ですが、

   ```
   .myblocks p {
     font-size: 1.1em;
     line-height: 2;
     color: #111111;
   }
   ```

   `.myblocks p` の箇所は下記の赤の横線の箇所でないとだめか

識者からの回答をお待ちしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

> 左の枠で囲ったコードに対応するのは右の青枠で囲んであるDOMの事か

スクリーンショットを見る限り、そのようです。

> `.myblocks p` の箇所は下記の赤の横線の箇所でないとだめか

ビューポートが 992px 以上であるときのみ質問文のカスタムスタイルシートを適用したいのであれば、赤横線のようにメディアクエリ内にそのルールセットを書く必要があります。

Comment: >>1.これが記述されていれば、下にStylesがあり、その中から変更すべきCSSを変える
これに関してはどうですか

>>.myblocks p の箇所は下記の赤の横線の箇所でないとだめか
この箇所というのはその上にある＠media～です。

Comment: 「これが記述されていれば、下にStylesがあり、その中から変更すべきCSSを変える」については、ご質問の内容が理解できませんでした。もう少し詳しく教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 「この箇所というのはその上にある＠media～です。」そのように想定して回答したのですが、何か問題がありましたか？